# Bounds for integral over $x^{-x}$

Tags: integration, inequality

Let $a,b>0$ and consider
$$
F(a,b) := \int_a^\infty x^{-b x}\, dx = \int_a^\infty \exp(- b x \log(x) ) \, dx
$$

For sufficiently large $a$ it holds
$$F(a,b) \leq \int_a^\infty \exp(-b x) \, dx = \exp(-ab)/b$$

But is there a way to get a tighter inequality?
I am also looking for an *lower* bound on $F(a,b)$.

Comment: Get rid of $b$ with $F(a,b)=\frac1b\int_{x=a/b}^\infty x^{-x}dx=\frac1b G(\frac ab)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\ge a\ge1$ then
$$
\int_a^\infty\exp(-\,b\,x\log x)\,dx\le\int_a^\infty \exp(-b\,x\log a)\,dx=\frac1{b\log a}\,\exp(-a\,\log a),
$$
which is tighter than your estimate for $a>e$.

For a lower bound you can use $\log x\le x/e$ and obtain a lower bound in terms of the error function:
$$
\int_a^\infty\exp(-\,b\,x\log x)\,dx\ge\int_a^\infty \exp(-b\,x^2)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \sqrt{b}}\,\text{erfc}\left(a\sqrt{b}\right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

For $x> 0$, from the relatively well known:

$$1-\frac1x \le  \log x \le x-1$$
$$\implies x-x^2 \le  -x\log x \le 1-x$$
$$\implies \int_t^\infty e^{x-x^2} dx \le \int_t^\infty x^{-x} dx \le \int_t^\infty e^{1-x}dx$$

$$\implies \frac{\sqrt[4]{e\pi^2}}{2b}\left(\text{Erf}(\tfrac12-\tfrac{a}b) +1\right)\le F(a, b) \le \frac1be^{1-a/b} $$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm dF(a,b)}{\mathrm da}=-\exp(-bx\log(x))$ which never zeros.

(Work in progress)